# Filtering elements from Django database on two conditions

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to select elements from my Django database on two conditions - whether the boolean value "used" is true and whether or not the "dateUsed" is within the last 20 days. However, my current filter statement is returning an empty QuerySet, even though there should be elements that meet both conditions. Am I filtering the elements correctly? I've attached the code that filters the elements, the definitions of my models, as well as the block of code that changes the value of "used" once the model elements have been displayed on my site.

Filter:

```
def pastSongs(request):
    window = datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=20)
    songHistory = Song.objects.filter(used = True).filter(dateUsed__gt = window)
    ent = {}
    ent["ent"] =  songHistory
    return render(request, 'rollingStone/songs.html',ent)
```

Models:

```
class Song(models.Model):
    rank = models.IntegerField()
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cover = models.URLField()
    writers = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    producers = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    releaseInfo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=3000)
    used = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    dateUsed = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

Changing "used" field:

```
def reload():
    # Change status of old song/album to used, and save the date that it was used
    if entry["status"] == "filled":
        currentSong = Songs.objects.get(entry["songEnt"].name)
        currentAlbum = Albums.objects.get(entry["albumEnt"].name)
        currentSong.dateUsed = datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=1)
        currentAlbum.dateUsed = datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=1)
        currentSong.used = True
        currentAlbum.used = True
        currentSong.save()
        currentAlbum.save()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "whether or not the "dateUsed" is within the last 20 days"?

Comment: Each day, a different element from my database should be displayed on my site. At the end of the day, the "used" field of that element should be changed to true ( to signify that it's been displayed) and the date that it was displayed should be stored in the "dateUsed" field. I want to have a history page that selects elements that were displayed in the last 20 days - i.e the "dateUsed" field has a value that is within the last 20 days.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be that you are doing something weird with the window date...

Other than that you could write a manager for your model:

managers.py:

```
from django.db.models import QuerySet, Q

SongQuerySet(QuerySet):
   def used_and_in_time_window(time_window):
       return self.filter(Q(used=True) & Q(dateUsed__gte=time_window))
```

models.py :

```
class Song(models.Model):
    rank = models.IntegerField()
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cover = models.URLField()
    writers = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    producers = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    releaseInfo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=3000)
    used = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    dateUsed = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    
    objects = SongQuerySet.as_manager()
```

usage:

```
def pastSongs(request):
    time_window = datetime.date(datetime.now()) - timedelta(days=20)
    songHistory = Song.objects.used_and_in_time_window(time_window)
    ent = {}
    ent["ent"] =  songHistory
    return render(request, 'rollingStone/songs.html',ent)
```

Also you might wanna pack the time delta value to an environment variable so you don't have to make a commit if you wanna change that in the future.